# 'Error 32 The type or namespace name 'ConnectionHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new developer of .net, I created connection Helper class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public static class DBConnectionHelper
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Calling to my cs file by using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DBConnectionHelper;



public partial class administration_login : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //var DBConnectionHelper= new DBConnectionHelper();

        using (var cn = DBConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users", cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
               Response.Write( rdr["first_name"].ToString()+ "<br>");
               // Response.Write(rdr[1].ToString()+"<br>"); //read a value
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Why i am getting error: Error   32  The type or namespace name 'ConnectionHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: You really should activate Windows.

Comment: okay, are you able to get the dbconnection class in intelligence

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that your class is `DBConnectionHelper`, not `ConnectionHelper` so your code should be:

```
using (var cn = DBConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
```

Your line of code `using DBConnectionHelper;` is not useful. `using` statements are for including namespaces as shortcuts but this isn't a namespace.

Comment: @amankhan: you are still using the wrong class name in the edited question. I've edited my answer to make clear where you are getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
using ConnectionHelper;
```

This directive will fail because DBConnectionHelper is not in a namespace. Declare your class as follow :

```
namespace ConnectionHelper
{
    public static class DBConnectionHelper
    {
        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
       {
            return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
       }
    }
}
```

Then change the call to your function by (wrong class name is used) :

```
using (var cn = DBConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
```